# php- Selected values are not showing?

Tags: php

Once click on edit the selected values are not showing.

Can any one tell where i have gone wrong!!.

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="code" >;
<option value="">select country</option>
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$coun_name = $wpdb->get_col("select country_name FROM countries ") ;
foreach($coun_name as $a)
{
<option value="<?php echo strtolower($a); ?>" <?php echo ($item["country"] == $a) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $a;?></option>
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: `$item["country"]` where is $item in your code. Do you even get value of `$item["country"]` try printing it first and check it gives the correct value or not

Comment: $item is a variable in which i am storing all the field data and inserting in to db..

Comment: i am able see the value in db .I have an option of edit ....if i click that the selected value is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating it wrong. The `<?php` part is not executed, but it is evaluated as string. You have 2 possible ways to accomplish it:

1. Use string concatenation in first echo:

   ```
   echo '<option value="'. strtolower($a) .'"' . ($item["country"] == $a ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>' . $a .'</option>';
   ```
2. Split it to multiple echos:

   ```
   echo '<option value="'. strtolower($a) .'" '; 
   echo $item["country"] == $a ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
   echo '>' . $a .'</option>';
   ```

Comment: what ever you have given its not showing the selected item.

Comment: i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the echo you can't use `<?php ?>` again. And some problem with your option tag. You miss to close the option tag for the first opening tag.

The be way to do this using separate HTML and PHP.

```
<option value="<?php echo strtolower($a); ?>" <?php echo ($item["country"] == $a) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $a;?></option>
```

**Updates:**

```
foreach($coun_name as $a)
{?>
    <option value="<?php echo strtolower($a); ?>" <?php echo ($item["country"] == $a) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $a;?></option>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: You have to close PHP tag before using it and also start `<?php`  again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113296/discussion-between-jmr-and-frayne-konok).

Comment: @ Frayne konok
Thanks Frayne konok
but selected = selected is not working
that is my concern.